# How would I decode this JSON with GSON (multi-d-array)?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am using GSON to decode JSON strings that are returned from our server.  I haven't had any problems, until I ran into this one particular JSON return from the API.  The return is in the following format:

**"success":1,"errors":[],"data":{"524":{"id":"524"}, "525":{"id":"525"}}**

For the other returns I had data as an array of a class of my own creation, but for this return it says that it is an object and not an array.  So how should I format my class?

***edit: What I am having trouble with is that the '524' and '525' fields are not static names.  They are dependent on what the user's credentials are.  There could be fields 323, 324, 325 or a single one 123.  It all depends.  How would I be able to handle this dynamically?

**SOLVED***
What I had to was make 'data' a `<String, Object>` hashmap in my custom class.  Then after the first decoding, I turned 'data' into an array of type Object [].  Then for each Object[i], I converted it into a JSON string.  After that I used gson.fromJson() to convert it into what I had originally intended for it to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the API is giving inconsistent results and you can't find a reason on your end why it is doing so, one option is to parse the object into a GSON `JSONObject o = gson.fromJson(String)` and then convert the data to a list if it is not one already by doing `o.getElement("data").isList()`, etc..

When this is complete, you can then create the object via `gson.fromJson(JSONObject,Class)`.  The alternative is to have two classes, one for each instance, but this seems sloppy if this is the only reason to have two different classes.

Comment: When I try JSONObject o = JSONObject.fromJson(String), I get the error that fromJson(String) is undefined...

Comment: It's in the http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html class, sorry

Comment: Thanks, but i still dont quite understand what I should do.  Right now I changed it so that 'data' is turned into a generic 'object' type.  So I did                                                                       Complaints_Return response = gson.fromJson(line,  Complaints_Return.class);   Now 'data' is just an object, but I have no problem decoding it.  Where would I go to get response.data into an array of sorts?     My problem with your above code is that I can't instantiate the objects like that; the types simply don't match up.  If u cud b specific that would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm saying you should *check* to see if it's of the type you expect.  If it's not, modify the JSONObject to convert the map to an array and then put it in the POJO

Answer (score 1):

GSON is correct. From server reply `data` is object with two members that are objects also. To be array `data` should have square brackets `[]` instead of curly brackets `{}`. More about JSON format [here](http://www.json.org/).

Server format was changed or you tried another API version or someone made bug on server side.

Comment: For the other API calls, data is always returned as an array or as a single object.  In those cases I could use @SerializedName to map the array and its variables to Java objects because I always knew what the names of the fields would be for those particular API calls.  For this one though, the '524' and '525' are dependent on the request parameters I send to the API; thus they are not static.  So how would I dynamically decode such a return?